# How do I customize my type's XAML attribute representation?

Tags: .net, xaml, serialization

Say I have a Date, or a Phone number, or some Class which I don't actually want to store as a string at runtime, but which could have a nice short string serialization for serialization as a XAML attribute:

```
<Person PhoneNumber="+1-123-123-1234"/>
```

How do I make my type serialized in that representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750605.aspx) for information on custom XAML Serialisation. [See here for an example.](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/16/XamlWriter.aspx)

Comment: The MSDN article I found pretty useless, but the other one is awesome.